# Distinguish empty regexp matches from no matches in Haskell

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

I'm trying to use `regex-pcre` but `regex-base` contains too many overloads for `RegexContext` so I don't know which one should I use for the task at hand.

I want to match a string against `(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)` regular expression the following way:

```
myMatch :: String -> Maybe (String, String, Maybe String)
```

Sample output:

- `myMatch "dfjdjk"` should be `Nothing` as there is no match
- `myMatch "foo-bar"` should be `Just ("foo", "bar", Nothing)` as there's no third capture group in the first alternative
- `myMatch "quux-quuxqu"` should be `Just ("quux", "quux", Just "qu")`
- `myMatch "quux-quux"` should be `Just ("quux", "quux", Just "")` as the third capture group is present but empty

It's not an assignment, I'm just baffled with how https://github.com/erantapaa/haskell-regexp-examples/blob/master/RegexExamples.hs don't contain code paths for situations where there are no matches or no capture groups

Comment: You need anchors: [**`^(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)$`**](https://regex101.com/r/ult5dP/1/)

Comment: it depends on what I want :) I want `"fdoifofoo-bardjfkj"` to be matched too :)

Comment: I might not get it, but your expression works in the way you describe: https://regex101.com/r/ult5dP/2

Comment: Use [`=~~`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2/docs/Text-Regex-Posix-Wrap.html#v:-61--126--126-) in order to wrap the `target` in a monad, like `Maybe`.

Comment: @4castle, can you put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of achieving it is using `getAllTextSubmatches`:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE

myMatch :: String -> Maybe (String, String, Maybe String)
myMatch str = case getAllTextSubmatches $ str =~ "(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)" :: [String] of
  []                      -> Nothing
  [_, g1, g2, "", "", ""] -> Just (g1, g2, Nothing)
  [_, "", "", g3, g4, g5] -> Just (g3, g4, Just g5)
```

When `getAllTextSubmatches` has `[String]` as return type, it returns an empty list if there is no match, or a list with all capturing groups (where index 0 is the whole match) of the first match.

Alternatively, if a matched group may be empty and you cannot pattern match on the empty string, you can use `[(String, (MatchOffset, MatchLength))]` as return type of `getAllTextSubmatches` and pattern match `MatchOffset` with -1 to identify unmatched groups:

```
myMatch :: String -> Maybe (String, String, Maybe String)
myMatch str = case getAllTextSubmatches $ str =~ "(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)" :: [(String, (MatchOffset, MatchLength))] of
  []                                                              -> Nothing
  [_, (g1, _), (g2, _), (_, (-1, _)), (_, (-1, _)), (_, (-1, _))] -> Just (g1, g2, Nothing)
  [_, (_, (-1, _)), (_, (-1, _)), (g3, _), (g4, _), (g5, _)]      -> Just (g3, g4, Just g5)
```

Now, if that looks too verbose:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern NoMatch = ("", (-1, 0))

myMatch :: String -> Maybe (String, String, Maybe String)
myMatch str = case getAllTextSubmatches $ str =~ "(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)" :: [(String, (MatchOffset, MatchLength))] of
  []                                               -> Nothing
  [_, (g1, _), (g2, _), NoMatch, NoMatch, NoMatch] -> Just (g1, g2, Nothing)
  [_, NoMatch, NoMatch, (g3, _), (g4, _), (g5, _)] -> Just (g3, g4, Just g5)
```

Comment: I can write a wrapper to signal unmatched groups with `Nothing` then. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

To distinguish when there is no match, use [`=~~`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2/docs/Text-Regex-Posix-Wrap.html#v:-61--126--126-) so that it will place the result in a `Maybe` monad. It will use `fail` to return `Nothing` if there are no matches.

```
myMatch :: String -> Maybe (String, String, Maybe String)
myMatch str = do
    let regex = "(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)"
    groups <- getAllTextSubmatches <$> str =~~ regex :: Maybe [String]
    case groups of
        [_, g1, g2, "", "", ""] -> Just (g1, g2, Nothing)
        [_, "", "", g3, g4, g5] -> Just (g3, g4, Just g5)
```

Comment: Will this fail on `foo-barfoo-bar`? I only need to match once. Is pattern matching on `mrSubList <$> x =~~ "(foo)-(bar)|(quux)-(quux)(q*u*u*x*)"` any better?

Comment: @nponeccop It's supposed to just give the first match. I haven't actually tested my code yet, so I may need to edit it, but hopefully this demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: the list is always 6 elements long, and unmatched captures are all `""`. Here is a short illustration: `(.*)foo|(.*)bar`. In Perl `$1` and `$2` are either `''` or `undef`, so unmatched capture groups can be distinguished from matched but empty ones.

Comment: @nponeccop I've got it working on my system now. I'm using `regex-pcre-builtin`. I wish it would be able to distinguish an unmatched capture group better, but `""` will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex-applicative`

```
myMatch = match re
re = foobar <|> quuces where
    foobar = (,,) <$> "foo" <* "-" <*> "bar" <*> pure Nothing
    quuces = (,,)
        <$> "quux" <* "-"
        <*> "quux"
        <*> (fmap (Just . mconcat) . sequenceA)
            [many $ sym 'q', many $ sym 'u', many $ sym 'u', many $ sym 'x']
```

or, with ApplicativeDo,

```
re = foobar <|> quuces where
    foobar = do
        foo <- "foo"
        _ <- "-"
        bar <- "bar"
        pure (foo, bar, Nothing)
    quuces = do
        quux1 <- "quux"
        _ <- "-"
        quux2 <- "quux"
        quux3 <- fmap snd . withMatched $
            traverse (many . sym) ("quux" :: [Char])
            -- [many $ sym 'q', many $ sym 'u', many $ sym 'u', many $ sym 'x']
        pure (quux1, quux2, Just quux3)
```